# What are the options for Bitcoin integration on Polkadot / with Substrate?

Tags: polkadot, bridge, interbtc, bitcoin

What are the options for Bitcoin integration on Polkadot / with Substrate?

Is there a way to allow users to deposit BTC, have smart contract / runtime rules that adjust balances (based on signed app specific transactions), whilst also allowing users to withdraw their balance? Does a simple example exist anywhere?

I've [noticed interBTC](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/q/1427/220), which looks great, though I haven't found an example along the lines of above... perhaps I am misunderstanding something though. Are there other options?

Comment: https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-bridges#resources-and-examples

Comment: Using InterBTC, yes - the user would deposit their BTC via Interlay. From there you could use Moonriver to build a SC around [xckBTC](https://docs.moonbeam.network/builders/xcm/xc20/xc20). Acala [EVM+](https://wiki.acala.network/learn/acala-evm/acala-evm-composable-defi-stack/composable-defi-stack#fully-composable-defi-primitives-in-evm-and-runtime) allows for SC's and cross-chain assets and they also have kBTC. You could build a parachain and open an HRMP channel with Interlay and put your logic in a runtime. You could build a SC's parachain, use ink!, and open an HRMP channel with Interlay.