# how to bring bitcoin in polkadot substrate chain?

Tags: polkadot, bridge, interbtc, bitcoin

I am going through this [article](https://stellaswap.medium.com/first-trustless-bitcoin-ibtc-launches-on-polkadot-moonbeam-c3638055a24a), where it talk about bringing bitcoin in substrate chain using `iBTC`. I am struggling to find resources about iBTC integrate in substrate chain. Someone please provide some resources. Thanks!

[iBTC github](https://github.com/interlay/interbtc)

Comment: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/3005/what-are-the-options-for-bitcoin-integration-on-polkadot-with-substrate

Answer (score 1):

Both interlay and hashed network are working on btc bridges(I think).
iBTC is wrapped btc, i would advice you to check out atomic swaps and:
https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-bridges